# Работа с map и string STL

Tags: stl, c++

Мне нужно каждой строке из файла присвоить номер в порядке возрастания и по этому номеру как ключу в map работать с отдельной строкой.

Второй вопрос: как использовать string в stl, чтобы было что-то наподобие массива и обращаться к каждому элементу массива как word[i].

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, ".866");
    setlocale (LC_ALL, ".1251");
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    std::map<std::string, int> table;
    std::string word;

    while(ifs >> word) 
    {
        table[word]++;
    }

    for(std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = table.begin(); it != table.end(); it++) 
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это вопрос куда? Если к тому, что я написал - то доступ к значениям производится по ключу, в качестве индексного доступа к примеру: чтобы получить строку находящуюся на второй позиции необходимо обратится к table[1] (нумерация с 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в чем была проблема? У Вас все правильно написано, но исходя из ваших требований достаточно просто поменять местами ключ и значение:

```
std::map<int, std::string> table;
```

И потом делаем в цикле следующее:

```
size_t i=0;
while(ifs >> word) 
{
    table[i++]=word;
}
```

Для корректной и полной работы со строками string - рекомендую подключать string.h, string.

Comment: какой смысл в
    map< int, T > ?
по-моему, в таких случаях логичнее использовать
    vector<T>

Comment: Человек разбирается как работать с хеш-таблицами, соответственно и ответ такой. Против вектора, или массива конечно ничего не имею.

Comment: можете подсказать как мне тогда можно обратиться к конкретной строке из файла?

Comment: doublepost, ответ выше: table[1] - обращение ко второй строчке, считанной из файла

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать